# How to get what model a member of a collection belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm assuming this is really simple, but for some reason, I can't find the answer anywhere. I have a model `class_profiles` which has many `parent_profiles` and has many `parent_invitations`. In the class_profiles.rb file, I have a method which returns a single, sorted collection of `parent_profiles` and `parent_invitations` like so:

```
  def parents
    list = parent_profiles.uniq
    list += parent_invitations.where(status_code: 0).uniq
    list.sort_by { |p| [p.last_name, p.first_name]}
  end
```

So far so good. Later on I use the following instance variable to hold that collection:

```
@parents = @class_profile.parents
```

Thus in `@parents`, I'll get something like this:

```
[
  #<ParentProfile id: 45, first_name: "John", last_name: "Collier", ...>,
  #<ParentInvitation id: 122, first_name: "Sally", last_name: "Duncan", ...>,
  #<ParentInvitation id: 54, first_name: "Jessica", last_name: "Eggers", ...>,
  ....
]
```

I have slightly different display logic for members of `@parents` based on whether they're a `ParentProfile` or `ParentInvitation`, so how can I get what model a member of `@parents` belongs to? I'm assuming there must be something like `@parents[0].model` but that doesn't work and I don't know the name of the method that accomplishes this. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `@parents[0].class` This will return you class name for object. if it doesn't work try `@parents[0].class.to_s` .

Comment: This is perfect. So easy.

Comment: FYI: `to_s` is not necessary. I was able to use `if @parents[0].class == ParentProfile`

Answer (score 0):

you could check it with `is_a?` like `@parents[0].is_a? ParentProfile`

Comment: Both answers are right, but Nitin's (below) came in first, so I gotta give him the green check...